# How to return error code from restful service when expecting JSON

Tags: php, json, rest

I am attempting to create a restful PHP web service which typically returns pure JSON data.  if something goes wrong on the web server side, lets say a bad SQL query, what is the correct restful way to let the user know something went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the exception on your server side code.
Log it.

Then pick one of the following HTTP Status code appropriate for the situation (REST basically returns http status codes). Error 500 seems good :)
http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Return that as JSON or XML, dependent upon your imeplentation to the client, along with either a nice error message or the raw error message (dependent upon whether you'd like the client to know)
FYI, preferably return a nice error message, instead of giving clients a peek into your back end data structures :)